# What would happen if you tried to build a GAE/Java project using Java 7?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-7

I'd like to use some Java 7 features in a GAE project.

Is this possible?

If not, what would happen if I tried to do this?

Comment: Great things have been discovered by people who weren't afraid of trying new things.

Comment: You might make time travel possible. Caution is advised.

Answer (score 3):

If you have not used any new APIs the code should be probably just a little faster if anything. The JVM is only interested in the byte-code generated. If the JavaC 7 *doesn't* produce an opcode that JavaC 6 *can't* understand then it really doesn't have a way of knowing you used a newer version!

This means you should be able to use String in case statements without problems.

They major caveat is that if you use classes or methods added by Java 7 then the could will fail, likely with an AbstractMethodError.

But yes, to repeat the others, just go try it out!